# Magento CSS Forbidden

Tags: magento-1.9, css, http-status-403

After the site has been properly working for awhile (year or so)... we get 403 Forbidden errors on CSS files hosted locally on the server. Changing permissions on the directories and files didn't work. This wasn't happening before. Any possible causes you guys can think of? The only change we made were some m2epro listings as well as adding considerable html to our descriptions, which still posed no issues for several days.

Comment: Can you check the permissions?

Comment: I reverted the server to a previous state so it works now. The permissions are the same now as they are during the error state. 644 for the css files. Owner is the main user name and group is www-data.